# Can a Groovy closure extend an abstract class

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-class

I have an abstract Java class that needs to have one method `onMessage` to be implemented. I know that a closure can easily implement a Java interface using the `as` keyword, but how can it extend an abstract Java class?

If it can't extend it, then whats the best work around possible in such cases in Groovy?

Here is my usage in Java, I am looking for something similar that can be done in Groovy.

```
MessageCallback callback = new MessageCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                dosomething();
            }
        };
```

Where message callback is my abstract class which I would like to use in a similar fashion in Groovy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do:

```
def callback = [ onMessage:{ message -> doSomething() } ] as MessageCallback
```

Does that not work?

***Edit***

To make a call from the Map method back to the Abstract class, the only way I can find to do it is:

```
// Dummy class for testing
abstract class MessageTest {
  abstract void onMessage( msg ) ;
  void done() { println "DONE!" }
}

// Create a Proxied instance of our class, with an empty onMessage method
def p = [ onMessage:{ msg -> } ] as MessageTest

// Then overwrite the method once we have access to the Proxy object p
p.metaClass.onMessage = { msg -> println msg ; p.done() }

// Test
p.onMessage( 'woo' )
```

Comment: That should work. In fact, if MessageCallback only has one method, you can just do this:  def callback = {message -> doSomething()} as MessageCallback

Comment: @tim_yates It worked partially, the messagecallback class had a method "done" which when I invoked inside the closure, I got the missing method exception. In java I just use done(), should I use some other syntax in Groovy?

Comment: Ahhh, if you need to call back into the Proxied class things get tricky...  I will have a look and see if I can come up with anything better than writing a concrete class with empty methods, and then overwriting these in the `metaClass` (which is the only other solution I can currently think of)

Comment: @Abe added a possible solution to my answer...  It's not as clean, but I can't currently find a better solution :-/

Comment: @tim_yates yeah not clean but thanks for the solution, I was stuck.

Comment: @tim_yates the test you provided worked but when I put the abstract class in another source file it does not work anymore. I get a GroovyCastException Script1.groovy: 1: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'MessageTest_groovyProxy' must be declared abstract or the method 'void onMessage(java.lang.Object)' must be implemented.

Comment: Guess this was an un-necessary q after all, the inner class as in java is working quite fine in groovy(1.8) also. No need for a closure here.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do this:

Implements a method in any class:

```
public MessageTest messageTest(Closure callback) {
    return new MessageTest() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            callback.call(message)
        }
    }
}
```

In main class in main method:

```
def outerMessage

MessageTest messageTest = messageTest() {message ->
    outerMessage = message
    println "innerMessage: $message"
}

messageTest.onMessage("This is the message...")
println "outerMessage: $outerMessage"
```

Your output should show this:

```
innerMessage: This is the message...
outerMessage: This is the message...
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing on @tim_yates, here is a version of method which creates  object of an abstract class from a closure. I needed something like that to be able instantiate such object in just one line.

```
// Dummy class for testing
abstract class MessageTest {
  abstract void onMessage( msg ) ;
  void done() { println "DONE!" }
}

MessageTest createMessageTest(Closure closure) {
  // Create a Proxied instance of our class, with an empty onMessage method
  def p = [ onMessage:{ msg -> } ] as MessageTest

  // Then overwrite the method once we have access to the Proxy object p
  p.metaClass.onMessage = closure
  return p
}

// Create
MessageTest mt = createMessageTest { msg -> 
  println msg ; 
  done() 
}

// Test
mt.onMessage( 'woo' )
```